# why search does not work when entered full name?

Tags: php, mysql

i am having problem that when i enter only first name eg; rahul it gives search results but when i enter full name eg; rahul kapoor it does not give anything and shows no such users.

i am using javascript for getting search results from search.php here is search.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$sql_res=
mysql_query("select * from users where first_name like '%$q%' or last_name like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$fname=$row['fname'];
$lname=$row['lname'];
$img=$row['profile_pic'];
$re_fname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$re_lname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$final_fname = str_ireplace($q, $re_fname, $fname);
$final_lname = str_ireplace($q, $re_lname, $lname);

?>
<div class="display_box" align="left">
<img src="usedata/profile_pics/
<?php echo $img; ?>" />
<?php echo $final_fname; ?>&nbsp;
<?php echo $final_lname; ?><br/>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{}
```

?>

Comment: `firstname !== 'rahul kapoor'` and `lastname !== 'rahul kapoor'` so no rows returned... if your search term is `rahul kapoor` you'll need to search on something like `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%$q%'`

Comment: Because you're searching each field for the whole name. You'll need to split the words from the query.

Comment: you query for full name is searching for full name in firstname or in in last name. like firstname like '%rahul kapoor%'. you need to split them up

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Baker and @BenM pointed out you may try something as

```
mysql_query("select * from users where first_name like '%$q%' or last_name like '%$q%' or concat(first_name,' ',last_name) = '$q' or concat(first_name,' ',last_name) like '%$q%'order by id LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: Use concat, not concate , I have a typo in the above query. It works I just checked having a similar table structure in development environment

Comment: @Manish its not copied and I was writing the solution and by that time 2 comments appear so I mentioned their name, that copy business could be a familiar attribute for you but not mine.

Comment: @user2281190 try this:`"select * from users where CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)  LIKE '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5"`.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, hey what i tried to point out, that you are not required to match all the three( firstn, lastn, both) separately, last one should cover the rest :D

Comment: You don't really need an `=` test _and_ a `like` test on the CONCAT() do you?

Comment: Yeah, thats a better solution :)

Comment: can you echo the query and post here ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
list($q1,$q2) = explode(" ", $q);
$sql_res=
    mysql_query("select * from users where (first_name like '%$q1%' OR first_name like '%$q2%') or (last_name like '%$q1%' OR last_name like '%$q2%') order by id LIMIT 5");
```

Or something similar.

It's because you have to split the first and last name...

Comment: what if first name has spaces :)